# JMeter - Extract value(x-nonce) from the Response Header

Tags: json, jmeter, json-extract

[I am unable to get the values of x-nonce from response Header,

I have to pass these X-nonce values in next API's, How can I get them and use?   ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4wqi.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole value you can do it using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configured like:

- Field to check: `Response Headers`
- Name of create variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `nonce`
- Regular Expression: `x-nonce?\s*:?\s* (.*)`
- Template: `$1$`

[image]

Explanation:

- `?\s*` - any number of optional [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)
- `(` and `)` - [grouping](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups)
- `.` - matches any character
- `*` - repetition

More information:

- [Apache JMeter - Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)